# DISCORD.PY How do i make it so only a certain role can click the button?

Tags: python, button, discord

I want to figure out how only administrators or someone with a certain role are allowed to click the buttons.
Here is the code below.

````
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Tryout", style=discord.ButtonStyle.success, emoji="✅", custom_id="TicketTRYOUT")
    async def tryout_callback(self, button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.user.send("does this work chat?")
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Interview", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="", custom_id="TicketINTERVIEW")
    async def interview_callback(self, button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Interview VC is being created...", ephemeral=True)
        await interaction.response.send_message("Interview VC has been created!", ephemeral=True)
        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Close Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="", custom_id="TicketCLOSE")
    async def close_callback(self, button, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Ticket is being closed...", ephemeral=False)
        await interaction.channel.delete()
        await interaction.user.send(f"Your ticket has been successfully closed!")```
````

Comment: You can check if the user has the admin role at the beginning of the callback, right? And if they don't, send an ephemeral message saying "You are not an admin" or something.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to make it only viewable to a role, but you could prevent a button press from going through by checking a users roles before the action is carried out in your callback.

```
allowed_role_id = 23984239732342 #role id(s)

        
    @discord.ui.button(label="Close Ticket", style=discord.ButtonStyle.red, emoji="", custom_id="TicketCLOSE")
    async def close_callback(self, button, interaction: discord.Interaction):

        #before trying to close the ticket, check roles

        allowed_role = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.roles, id=allowed_role_id)
        #place where you want, preferably at the start of the slash command if you plan to use it multiple times

        if allowed_role is None or allowed_role not in interaction.user.roles:
                await interaction.response.send_message("You do not have permissions to close this ticket", ephemeral=True)
        if allowed_role in interaction.user.roles:
                await interaction.response.send_message("Ticket is being closed...", ephemeral=False)
                await interaction.channel.delete()
                await interaction.user.send(f"Your ticket has been successfully closed!")
```